# Standard Widgets Toolkit - Tooltip

Tags: java, swt

I'm pondering over this,

I have a swt tooltip being set on a label. The tooltip  method will be called setTooltip(message) will be called from a different class and the setMessage(message) will be set in the class where tooltip object will be created. Right now Im checking for null or empty condition before setting the tooltip message otherwise it would throw IllegalArgumentException. So my code is as such

```
public void setTooltip(String message) {
if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
tooltip.setMessage(message);
label.addMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
iconLabel.addMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
} else {
label.removeMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
iconLabel.removeMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
}
}
```

I need an option in the else condition because the control goes to removeListener line eben if null is passed and tooltip has not been associated with the listener.

I do not know how the control flow happens here. Can someone elaborate on this. 
I would explicitly set tooltip to an empty string in the else condition, so there's no chance of some previous value being set on the tooltip, Such as

```
else {
tooltip.setMessage("");
label.removeMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
iconLabel.removeMouseTrackListener(mouseTrackListener);
}
```

This way callers can pass null/empty into this method to remove the tooltip, if desired. Is this possible? If so how does the above else condition work and how the control flows? I should have an else condition which I do not want to remove but I need to know how to achieve this.

Comment: What is `tooltip`? Are you aware of the `setToolTipText` method on controls that does tool tips without needing mouse tracking?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of setTooltipText but not to make it hard coding I pass a string in setTooltip(string) from another class and set the tooltip using tooltip.setMessage() in the class I create tooltip object. If I use setTooltipText then It would be specific to one single class but I'm working on eclipse with multiple packages and several JAVA files. So I want it this way. Can u please suggest something?

Comment: tooltip is the Tooltip class's object -->   Tooltip tooltip = new ToolTip(parent.getShell(), SWT.NONE);